# FDR for Posterior Probability?

Tags: bayesian, posterior, false-discovery-rate

I searched this community for any explanation for Posterior Probability FDR and found nothing that answers the question. I googled for it and found different solutions for particular cases. If there is a good answer for the question - I will close it as a duplicate.

I did analysis and got posterior odds for multiple "tests" as an output. Posterior odds are tests' statistics. How can I make an FDR cutoff based on this? The distribution of posteriors can be of different shape.

Evident solution: permute labels of data points and priors and make a lot of posteriors calculations, it will make a background model. Are there more efficient ways (like BH methods for posteriors)?

Comment: This is a nice explanation of the relationship between posterior error probability and FDR.

http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/pr700739d